# Is an S-Corp required to pay the sole owner/employee a wage if the S-Corp only has passive income?

Tags: united-states, s-corporation, payroll-taxes

S-Corp has passive income; does the single person owner need to be paid a wage on payroll?

Comment: Related: [What is a reasonable salary for the owner and sole member of a small S-Corp?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/36818/10997)

Comment: Related: [Can an S-Corp pay the sole owner/employee with a 1099?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/133041/10997)

Comment: Actually a pretty interesting question.